# c# Finishing a BPF(Business Process Flow)

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

As mentioned in the blog below, could the attribute, _bpf_accountid_value be used when not found in the default solution? Trying something similar with leads, I am trapping the error "the given key not present in dictionary".
I am on the lead form and for testing purposes I traverse the BPF and without manually finishing it,
I am trying to make my custom workflow "Finish" it, on demand.

I hesitate to show my code because it is commented with various attempts and will only loose the focus of this specific question.

Please help.

https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/crmmemories/posts/finish-a-business-process-flow-in-c

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I just verified in my instance as the BPF will have its own entity, I can find those attributes. You can check too [using CRM REST Builder](https://www.wipfli.com/insights/articles/tc-crm-rest-builder-dynamics-crms-web-api) or the native Advanced find - download fetchxml.

There is a difference between OOB like Lead entity BPF and custom entity BPF like below: (`_bpf_xxx_projectinspectionsid_value` vs `_leadid_value`)

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/xxx_inspectionflows(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)?$select=_bpf_xxx_projectinspectionsid_value,bpf_name,businessprocessflowinstanceid

https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/leadtoopportunitysalesprocesses(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)?$select=businessprocessflowinstanceid,_leadid_value
```